# What do you call these corridors that link two buildings?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call these corridors that link two buildings? Is there a name for it? I am wondering if it's just called a bridge or if there's a specific name to these types of corridors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That could be called a "[skyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyway)". Wikipedia says:

> A skyway, skybridge, or skywalk is a type of pedway consisting of an enclosed or covered footbridge between two or more buildings in an urban area.

I found that word by typing "bridge between two buildings" into a search engine.

Comment: I believe that, from time to time, they have had several names, often invented by the architect! Sky bridge (because it's so far up in the air) or more mundane just link are two that spring to mind.

Comment: @PeterJ - I've heard them called _catwalks_, even though that term often refers to open-air (rather than enclosed) footbridges. From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/catwalk): _A catwalk is a narrow bridge high in the air, for example between two parts of a tall building, on the outside of a large structure, or over a stage._

Comment: @J.R. Yes, that's another possibility, but as you say, a catwalk is usually understood to be an open structure, not enclosed. Also often found high above the stage in theatres for the use of the stage hands when working on lights and scenery.

Comment: @PeterJ - Yes, but context can cure that. If you and I worked in that building, and I said, "Oh, James works over in the other tower. We'll have to take the catwalk to go see him," you'd probably know what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows the Petronas Twin Towers in Malaysia, and they specifically refer to it as the "Skybridge", see https://www.petronastwintowers.com.my/design-and-structures/

A famous bridge connecting 2 buildings in Venice, Italy, is called the "Bridge of Sighs".  There's another similar bridge in Cambridge, UK, also called the "Bridge of Sighs".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_of_Sighs_(disambiguation)

I guess it's such a rare architectural feature that there's no generic term for it.